# Why is time complexity of factoring expressed for $2^n$ and not $N$?

Tags: prime-factorization

The question I have is what is in the comment of the question:

[Why is the time complexity of factorization $2^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202742/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-factorization-2n)

The original author didn't mention why we are considering the input size in bits and not base 10.

Comment: Computers famously operate in binary, so it makes sense to have our input in base 2 rather than base 10.

Comment: In complexity theory, we are concerned with the number of symbols required to represent an input or output. Representing a number in base 2 as opposed to base 10 only makes a constant factor in the size of the representation.

Comment: @RobArthan, what's the constant factor in this case? $2^n$ looks like a forever growing value.

Comment: 1 base 10 digit can be represented in $\log_210$ base 2 digits.

Comment: Anyone of you like to put in an answer so I can vote on it?